# Finding the sides of a right triangle when a relationship between them is given.

Tags: geometry

Given a ratio between the sides of a right triangle *a : b : c*, where *c* is the hypotenuse and *a* and *b* are the legs. For example suppose that we have the ratio *18-x : 12 : x* between the sides of the right triangle. It is my understanding that we can immediately conclude that *x=13* since this satisfies the ratio *5 : 12 : 13* which is one of the well known Pythagorean triples.

I cannot understand however how exactly this conclusion is justified. How do we know **for certain** that there cannot exist another positive real number other than *13* which when substituted for *x*, also satisfies the Pythagorean identity and the relationship between the sides?

On a case by case basis, I can reach polynomial equations by applying the Pythagorean theorem that lead to the conclusion that there exists only one positive real number that satisfies the given ratio. It seems obvious that this should be the case for every situation but I cannot put my finger on exactly why it is so.

I can understand a simpler result which I suppose might be helpful with moving onto the result I cannot understand: Suppose we are given the ratio *x : 12 : 13*. We are justified in concluding *x=5* because we can construct a right triangle with leg lengths of *5* and *12* which results in a hypotenuse of length *13*. We can then say that this triangle is congruent to the first  by the Hypotenuse-Leg Conrguence Theorem thus having *x=5*.

I do not see how I can (or whether I can) relate this result to my original question.

Comment: In the specific case given in the first paragraph, can you write a quadratic equation and show that the only solutions are $x = 13, 25$?  But then, we also require $ x < 18$ for positive lengths, hence $13$ is the unique answer.

Comment: That is right, I have overlooked that. I will edit my question to fix that but my question still stands.

Comment: Okay, so we could let the second leg be *x-1* and the unique answer for *x* would still be *13*. I don't  think it makes a major difference whether we have two sides or all three sides as expressions in one variable. My question arises whenever there is more than one side with an unknown expression. Though I suppose writing all three sides with unknowns could complicate things even further.

Comment: No. My point is that in the case of $18-x: 12 : x$, you want to solve for $(18-x)^2 + 12^2 = x^2$. This is a quadratic equation which is well understood (Do you know how to solve quadratic equations? Context like that would be helpful.). If we have a quadratic, then there are at most 2 solutions. $\quad$ In the more general case, it depends on what the ratios are. EG if you want the ratio of $ 18 - x^2 : 12 : x+1$, then you end up with a degree 4 polynomial, which is more complicated.

Comment: Yes I do understand that we find *x* to be *13*  **if** we apply the pythagorean theorem and work out the equation we find. But I am asking how can we conclude **in general** that we would not end up with more than one positive real roots which would result in more than one distinct triangles that satisfy the given relationship between the sides? For example, the quadratic in this question gives us 13 as the only root (because it really reduces to a linear equation.) How do we generalize this is what I'm asking.

Comment: Take the ratio *(x-1) : x : (x+1)* for example. If we apply the pythagorean theorem, we end up with a quadratic with two distinct real roots, namely *0* and *4*. But we cannot allow any non-positive number as a side length so we do not consider *0* and we say that *4* is the unique solution which gives us the *3 : 4 : 5* triangle. How could we know that we could **never** end up with more than one positive real root given other pythagorean triples and/or relationships between the sides?